# Separate assets repo for multiple Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, assets

Using Rails 3 and Ruby 2. I have the following apps:

1. App A
2. App B

Now app A and app B talk to each other via API. This is SOA. As the apps grow bigger, I found that the apps have CSS and Javascripts that can be re-used across the apps. I want to separate the assets (CSS, JS) to a different repo (e.g. app C), so that app A and B can just use the same assets repo.

Here are my questions:

1. For deployment, app C should precompile and minify, and app A and B should point to that repo. What are the options?
2. For development, app C should not be minified, but how should app A and B talk to app C continuously to get all changes on CSS/JS in app C?

I have searched through Google, but couldn't get much results. Perhaps my keywords were wrong. Please feel free to name the terms/conventions used for this practice.

If there are other better practices, please feel free to suggest too.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest option might be to use a [`git submodule`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to share the assets files themselves between your two projects/apps.

Another option is to create your own gem with those assets files in it, and use that gem in both of your projects. This would require a little more work up front, but would be easier to manage versions down the track (git submodules need a few more manual steps to keep things updated as you change the submodule repository).

Comment: But the app C (assets) will be updated very often. Keep bundle installing all the time is quite an hassle, isn't it?

Comment: Both solutions would require you to do something every time your assets repo is updated, you either need to change into some directory and `git pull` or run `bundle update your-assets-gem` - either way you have something to do (in fact less to do for the gem, because you don't have to change into a different directory :)

Comment: You know, there's a better way to thank people here on StackOverflow :)

Comment: I'm sorry. It's a good opinion, but doesn't fit me yet. I will upvote.